# Using UUID as feature ID for MVT tiles (PostGIS)

Tags: postgis, vector-tiles

I have a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database with with rows identified by UUID.
I export those rows as vector tiles.

I want to identify the features within the tiles.

The documentation https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsMVT.html says

> feature_id_name is the name of the Feature ID column in the row data. If NULL or negative the Feature ID is not set. The first column matching name and valid type (smallint, integer, bigint) will be used as Feature ID, and any subsequent column will be added as a property. JSON properties are not supported.

And I get the following error:

> PG::InternalError: ERROR:  mvt_agg_transfn: Could not find column 'id' of integer type

However, the specification seems to accept anything that would be unique https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec/tree/master/2.1#42-features

My supposition here is that PostGIS is too restrictive.

*Edit* : I looked into the protobuf description of MVT and ID must indeed be a 64 bit *unsigned* integer https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec/blob/master/2.1/vector_tile.proto#L32

Is there some way to get my feature identifiers in the MVT? Losing some information could be acceptable (and I will set the UUID as a property), but I need an unique ID across all tiles to manipulate the data with maplibre-gl-js. I would like to avoid adding a extra column for an other id.

As UUID are 128 bits, and bigint are “only” 64 bits, I don’t think I can cast my UUID to an integer.

For now I did this ugly thing:

`SELECT abs(('x'||md5(rows.id::text))::bit(64)::bigint) AS id`

It should in practice work; the risk of collisions would be pretty low and it wouldn’t be a big deal, but it’s not really satisfying.

It turns out the id must also be positive

Comment: UUIDs are too random to be effective ID columns. If the documentation says only `smallint`, `int`, and `bigint` are supported, then I think you should accept that (if you can't manage with *only*  9223372036854775807 unique features, maybe PostgreSQL shouldn't be your solution)

Comment: Integers are too predictable to be effective ID columns ;) More seriously, there are many reasons to use UUIDs as rows identifiers, and it is considered as a good practice (see https://blog.codinghorror.com/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids/ for a very short list of pros).

Comment: In MVT the integer ID is fixed in the specification. Many other GIS formats do the same, for example GeoPackage. But for some formats string/UUID is ok as a feature ID, for example GeoJSON and GML. Integer ID is usable for more formats, if interoperability is needed. There are many point of views and much place for opinions.